# How to display Grouped product without using image and other details..?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have one Bazaar store to develop in Magento. I have created grouped product, with simple product. As per requirement I want to display only Product name and list of product(Which I added in grouped product), Other details like image,and tags,etc don't want to display. For this What things I need to do. Which file I need to override or need to create a new module or need to implement any other technique. Please suggest me what way I follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the main product page view (not the list view, i.e. category or search) then you need to look at the catalog/product/view.phtml template file.

Here you can customise how the product is displayed and if you need to test for a grouped product you can use

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped')
```

And then customise how you want to display the grouped product.

i.e.

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped'): ?>
    //grouped product data
<?php else: ?>
    //other product data
<?php endif; ?>
```

You will also need to customise the child html in catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml for the simple products of the grouped products in a similar way.

Comment: Please can you explain me more..Because I saw view.phtml file. If I comment out long description. I think it might be reflected on simple product. So how should I customize I am not getting an idea.

Comment: yes, so for product data you don't want to show for grouped products you need to test for a grouped product and then modify the html as you wish. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Please can you provide me one sample code with few content on Grouped product..?

Comment: This way I successfully remove the description and other details .Now only image is remains. How should I remove it.

Comment: Look in view.phtml where the image html is rendered and do the same product check.

Comment: Ok let me check..

Comment: Thanks a lot paj for your instant reply..so I can solve it immediately..